# forcibly redirect to correct folder

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp-2.1

I am new in htaccess.
I updated some SEO pages in my live site after one day some Url changes came so i changed the url again. but google already indexed it. So i want if some one found old url it will redirect to new url But in case of SEO pages only not for other pages.It means it wont affect to any other place.and there are not one page(it is 40-50 pages) can anybody give answer through htaccess or cakephp.

Old Url-

```
www.testenergy.com/test-energy-reviews
```

new url-

```
www.testenergy.com/s/test-energy-reviews
```

And there are also four senario-

```
www.testenergy.com/test-energy-reviews

www.testenergy.com/Test-Energy-Reviews

www.testenergy.com/s/test-energy-reviews

www.testenergy.com/s/Test-Energy-Reviews
```

All these four links will redirect to `www.testenergy.com/s/test-energy-reviews` Url only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite rules somewhere, you probably want to stick to mod_rewrite. You'll need to add these to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably **above** any other rules that are there:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?test-energy-reviews$ /s/test-energy-reviews [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?s/Test-Energy-Reviews$ /s/test-energy-reviews [L,R=301]
```

The `NC` flag ignores case, so it covers both `/test-energy-reviews` and `/Test-Energy-Reviews`. The second rule takes care of `/s/Test-Energy-Reviews`

I'm not sure why `/s/test-energy-reviews` (3rd one) is one of your scenarios, since it is exactly what you want to redirect to.

Comment: but this an example file name just like this I have 50 pages for all the pages do I have to write?

Comment: @Ayesha unless there's a common pattern in all the pages that you can encapsulate in a regular expression, you're going to need to create rules for all your pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try This ..!!

```
Router::redirect('/test-energy-reviews', 'http://www.testenergy.energy/s/test-energy-reviews');
```

Comment: This one is not ignoring uppercase can you give solution for both uppercase and lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

write this line in Controller.

/******************* Redirect Url fo small letter if some one type in uppercase in url bar****/

preg_match( '/[A-Z]+/',$this->params->url, $upper_case_found );

if(count($upper_case_found)) {

// Now redirect to lower case version of url

```
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
 header("Location: " . ROOTPATH.strtolower($this->params->url) );die(); 
}
```

/********** End Code**************/

OR in htaccess write following code:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?test-energy-reviews$ /s/test-energy-reviews [L,NC,R=301]